# JQUERY | Mousedown and Mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I was wrote code but code not stable. I do mousedown, select code character and I do mouseup , still select code character. 
 I want mouse click hold . I mean mousedown method. I want to drag and select a word. Like a [Word Hunt Game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apptornado.word)

Problem is when i do mouseup still work mousedown method.

Please Help

```js
$( ".table li" ).mousedown(function() {
  $('.word').append($(this).text()); 
  $( ".table li" ).mouseenter(function() {
 
$('.word').append($(this).text());
});
   });
$( ".table li" ).mouseup(function() {
$(".word").empty();
   });
```

```css
#tablo {width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #cccdd2; overflow: hidden; }
.table {text-align: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 20px;}
.table ul { list-style: none outside none; margin-bottom: -12px;}
.table li { position: relative; border-radius: 100px; display: inline; display: inline-block ;  margin-right: -10px;}
.table li {width: 50px; height: 33px; margin: 2px; background-color: #666464;   padding-top: 17px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; color: #fff; }
.table li {  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */ -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */   user-select: none;}
.table li:hover {background-color: red; }
.word { width: 100%; text-align: center;
  background-color: black; border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px; 
font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word"></div>

 <div id="tablo">
    <div class="">Please find clock </div>
  <div class="table">
   <ul class="one">
       <li>A</li>
       <li>B</li> 
       <li>C</li>
       <li>D</li>
       <li>E</li> 
   </ul>
   <ul class="two">
       <li>O</li>
       <li>L</li> 
       <li>H</li>
       <li>I</li>
          <li>J</li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="one">
       <li>C</li>
       <li>L</li> 
       <li>M</li>
       <li>N</li>
       <li>O</li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="one">
       <li>K</li>
       <li>Q</li> 
       <li>R</li>
       <li>S</li>
          <li>T</li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="one">
       <li>U</li>
       <li>V</li> 
       <li>X</li>
       <li>Y</li> 
       <li>z</li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Hi I was wrote code but code not stable. I do mousedown, select code character and I do mouseup , still select code character. 
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your JavaScript code, when you trigger mousedown, you create a new eventListener that always adds text on mouseenter of one `.table li` element. After you created that eventListener this action will always be triggered until you would remove that eventListener.

However, if you just want to add text to the bar on the top on click, there is a click event you can trigger.

I edited your code example to accomplish that:

```js
var mouseIsDown = false;

$(".table li").mousedown(function() {
  mouseIsDown = true;
  $('.word').append($(this).text());
});
$(".table li").mouseup(function() {
  mouseIsDown = false;
  $(".word").empty();
});

$(".table li").mouseenter(function() {
  if(mouseIsDown) {
    $('.word').append($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```css
#tablo {width: 100%; text-align: center; background-color: #cccdd2; overflow: hidden; }
.table {text-align: center; overflow: hidden; padding: 20px;}
.table ul { list-style: none outside none; margin-bottom: -12px;}
.table li { position: relative; border-radius: 100px; display: inline; display: inline-block ;  margin-right: -10px;}
.table li {width: 50px; height: 33px; margin: 2px; background-color: #666464;   padding-top: 17px; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bolder; color: #fff; }
.table li {  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */ -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */   user-select: none;}
.table li:hover {background-color: red; }
.word { width: 100%; text-align: center;
  background-color: black; border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px; 
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word"></div>

<div id="tablo">
  <div class="">Please one word click and </div>
  <div class="table">
    <ul class="one">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li> 
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
      <li>E</li> 
    </ul>
    <ul class="two">
      <li>O</li>
      <li>L</li> 
      <li>H</li>
      <li>I</li>
      <li>J</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="one">
      <li>C</li>
      <li>L</li> 
      <li>M</li>
      <li>N</li>
      <li>O</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="one">
      <li>K</li>
      <li>Q</li> 
      <li>R</li>
      <li>S</li>
      <li>T</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="one">
      <li>U</li>
      <li>V</li> 
      <li>X</li>
      <li>Y</li> 
      <li>z</li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: no, i didn't explain very well  . I want mouse click hold .
I mean mousedown method.
I want to drag and select a word.
Like a Word Hunt Game.  [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apptornado.word)

Comment: I edited my JavaScript part. Now when starting mousedown on the table and hold it it will add letters to the bar. After release it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Mousedown and mouseup events are working fine. And working in most of browsers.It may have problem in touch device. If you want to use them in touch device, you may need tap and taphold events. please check

jquerymobile
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html

you can also check jquery browser-support
http://jquery.com/browser-support/

if it is not supported in your browser, you can use pure javascript to achieve it . 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp